# remove empty child array from array

Tags: laravel

I have a problem which is that I have a array and in this array also a sub array I want to delete the sub-array that do not contain any values instead of the [] to null

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This recursive function should do the trick... will only touch empty arrays

```
<?php


function emptyArraysToNull(&$object){
    if(is_array($object))
    foreach ($object as $key => &$value) {
      if (is_array($value)) {
        $value = emptyArraysToNull($value);
      }
      if (empty($value)) {
        $object[$key] = null;
      }
    }
    return $object;
    }


// TEST

$very_nested_array = [
        [
            "name" => "test",
            "id" => 1,

            "districts" => [
                "id" => 2,
                "districts" => [],
                "test" => []
            ]
        ],
        [
            "id" => []
        ]
    ];


print_r(emptyArraysToNull($very_nested_array));
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "test"
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["districts"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(2)
      ["districts"]=>
      NULL
      ["test"]=>
      NULL
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

Live demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4644ec81b623d9cd0c79e1aa67ab55a64cd9416d